# TypeError: Cannot set property '18dit075' of undefined in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, file, express

```
var id = req.query.id;
var username = req.query.name;
var password = req.query.password;
console.log(req.query);

var data = {
        people:{
        }
    }

    data.people[id] = {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            degignation : 1
    }


let userjson = jsonfile.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'database','people'));
console.log(userjson);
userjson.people[id] = {
                username: username,
                password : password,
                degignation: 1
        }


jsonfile.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'database','people'),userjson,{spaces:2});`
```

i want to write js object in json file. but it show the error TypeError: Cannot set property '18dit075' of undefined in node js.  note my people.json file is empty. i need a help in express js. please help me

Comment: What is `jsonfile`?

Comment: `userjson.people` is `undefined`.

Comment: jsonfile is fs module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.stringify` while writing to JSON. You also need to use `.json` as an extension.

Better yet you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/write-json-file & https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-json-file to avoid minor errors :)

Here's how I'd do it:

```js
const loadJsonFile = require('load-json-file');
const writeJsonFile = require('write-json-file');
const id = req.query.id
const username = req.query.name
const password = req.query.password
console.log(req.query)

(async () => {

    const data = {
        people: {},
    }

    data.people[id] = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        degignation: 1,
    }

    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'database/people.json')
    let userjson = await loadJsonFile(filePath);
    console.log(userjson)
    userjson.people[id] = {
        name: username,
        password: password,
        degignation: 1,
    }

    await writeJsonFile(filePath, userjson, {indent: 2});

})();
```